# Installing git on remote server and pushing local repository

Tags: ruby, git

I know this question has probably been asked a few times but I can't find an exact example of what i'm looking to do and for some reason I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a local ruby on rails repo i'm ready to share with another developer, could someone give me a run through(or point me in the right direction) of creating the new repository by PUSHING my local repo up to it?

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend bitbucket (Free up to 5 users) as a hosted git service. They have great documentation:

EDIT:

create repo
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Create+a+repository

push
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project

Comment: Do they allow private repo's?

Comment: Yes they allow private repositories and they are also free up to 5 users.

Comment: Hmm although thats not what I was asking, thats actually a much tidier solution +1 for thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage your own remote git repo, then

Make a bare clone of the repo

```
git clone --bare my_git_project my_git_project.git
```

Copy the bare repo to remote server

```
scp -r my_git_project.git gituser@remoteserver.com:/opt/git
```

Then login to the remote server and go to the git folder

```
ssh gituser@remoteserver.com
cd /opt/git/my_git_project.git
```

Then run this command

```
git init --bare --shared
```

At this point, any user who has ssh access to the remoteserver.com and write permissions on /opt/git/my_git_project.git will also have push access

A software such as [Open source GitlabHQ](http://gitlab.org) is highly recommended if you wish to manage your own git hosting. Gitlab also has a hosted version [gitlab cloud](http://www.gitlab.com/cloud/) with unlimited **free** private repos and unlimited collaborators. Of course they also have paid version.